# how to fetch my image from my database where my upload path folder?

Tags: php, mysql, image, broken-image

i already look in stackoverflow where i have a similar problem. but it wont just work on me.

Is it possible that the problem is how i upload my image into the folder?
this is the common answer in the stackoverflow and they say it work but it wont work on me the image will still display broken.

Ps. im sorry if the problem is not specify enough. this my first asking here in stackoverflow

this is just an example to what i have:

```
<?php
include('session.php');

$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from tbl_menu");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

 echo "<img src='Image_name/".$res['image']."'>";
}
?>
```

this is how i upload my image:

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['AddMenu'])){

$uploadimage = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/thesis/Images_name/'.$_FILES["image"]["name"];

    $mname =$_POST['mname'];
    $price =$_POST['price'];
    $mcategory =$_POST['mcategory'];
    $image =$_FILES['image']['name'];


mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into tbl_menu(mname, price, mcategory, image) values('$mname', '$price', '$mcategory', '$image')");


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $uploadimage)) {
    $msg = "image upload";
}else {
    $msg = "not upload";
}
header("location: menu.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$res['image']`? What is the relative path from your PHP file to the image file? Does the file exist at that location? Which [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is reported for the file in your browser console?

Comment: Image_name is the folder where i upload my images

Comment: im not really sure if word path is the right word for the question but the Image_name is the folder where if my database is inserted the image will upload in Image_name

Comment: Yes. the value $res['image'] is admin.png in my database. yes i think so. it shows just a broken image. that is the code that i try. i hope you bare with me plss im not really good at this

Comment: the <img> tag is outputted correctly because if my image is uploaded directly to my pages folder and i do it like this "<img src='".$res['image']."'>"; the image will work

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems in your code, provided that relative URL is correct and valid image files exist. I suggest [inspecting the image element](https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/) to see what HTML has been outputted by the PHP code. If the `src` is correct, [check the status](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/http-errors-404) of the image file for any informative errors; you might find it's Forbidden or Not Found, etc.

Comment: i tried to check if the file_exists. It doesn't.

Comment: In that case, yes I think the "problem is how i upload my image into the folder". Can you edit that part of your code into your question?

Comment: done. plss help

Comment: You're uploading into `Images_name` ("Images" plural) but then trying to serve a file from `Image_name` ("Image" singular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo "<img src='http://localhost/thesis/Image_name/".$res['image']."'>";
```

I would recommend you save a variable "home" as "http://localhost/thesis/" in your main config file. and use that variable where ever you need.

Comment: @JMFelicilda It doesn't seem it would work if you're writing to `Images_name/`. Was that just a typo in the code above?

Comment: the original in Images/ really so i got wrong when i edited

Comment: `/Images_name/` works if the directory images_name is at the same level as the script, because its relative to your current page. but if you are on a different page it would break. However if you use `../Images_name`, it would work as well, coz you are going back a directory then going in that one. Its better habit of using a `$home` variable so that you would not have to change it everywhere on changing servers, to avoid confusion.